# Do I need to use GPG subkeys for my backups?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm reading a lot about the need to separate the master key from additional encrypting or signing keys, like these links:

- [GPG subkey layout. Separate keys for C, S and E?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97059/gpg-subkey-layout-separate-keys-for-c-s-and-e)
- https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair/
- https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2013/12/02/creating-a-new-gpg-key-with-subkeys/

As I'm actually planning to use GPG only for protecting my backup data, is it useful to go trough all this procedure?

Comment: @downvoter: I think it'd be fair if you explained your critique, so that the OP can improve.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is *not* able to decrypt information encrypted for a subkey. If you encrypted your backup for a subkey and lose access to the private subkey, you cannot decrypt your backup any more.

Things are different with signing. If you lose a private signing subkey, you revoke it and generate a new one. You will never have to use the old signing subkey again, as signatures are verified through the public subkey.